# C++/CLI - syntax for referencing static method from certain namespace

Tags: static, namespaces, c++-cli, static-methods

I want to execute a static method from certain class in certain namespace, but I have a problem with using it as a method parameter.

Example:

Lets say there is a class:

```
namespace ExampleNamespace {
        public ref class A
        {
        public:
            static int MethodA();
        };
}
```

And I want to use MethodA in other namespace as a other's method parameter:

MethodB(MethodA());

Only way I can make it work is by writing it like this:

```
ExampleNamespace::A^ a;
MethodB(a->MethodA());
```

Is there a way to write it without that 'a' declaration before?
Something like

```
MethodB(ExampleNamespace::A->MethodA())
```

wont work...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 MethodB(ExampleNamespace::A::MethodA());
```